# C++ Problems Displaying Doubles with cout

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, cout

I have this simple class and can't figure out how to get the doubles to display properly.
Currently the are displayed as **"0.00"**. Without 'showpoint' and 'setprecision()' they were displaying as random numbers (ex: 6.95326e-310). **Minutes is an integer, price is where the problem is**

```
output() const{
    cout << "Title: " << title;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) <<
    "\nMinutes: " << get_minutes() << "\nPrice: ";
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << get_price();
    cout  << "\n";
```

Comment: What do you assume as a proper output?

Comment: Why do you say `6.95326e-310` is random?  It looks pretty close to `0` to me.

Comment: Should have made this more clear. The value is set to 9.99.

Comment: I'd suggest rounding error, when you start forcing it to 2 digits after the dot. And since it is a floating point value i also suggest an arithmetic error within the calculations rooted in the precision of double. So `6.95326e-310` is not random.

Answer (score 1):

6.95326e-310 is not a random number. It's called [scientific notation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/scientific/) and is able to show very small or very large numbers without using too many digits. If you don't want that, then set a default precision on `cout`:

```
std::cout.precision(2);
```

Comment: It appears that not setting the double's value in an intializer list was my problem. Tried to set it in the constructor.